# Add filter to prores file

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, transcoding, davinci-resolve

I have captured some Mini-dv home videos to .avi.
With ffmpeg I converted to prores v2 .mov files.
Now i need to add yadiff filter.(interlaced -> noninterlaced)
Is is possible to "update" my files with the yadif filter without write a complete new file ?
If not, how do I preserve my movie/audio quality/filesize while adding the yadif filter.
Is ffmpeg -i file1.mov -vf yadif -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 2 -c:a copy New-File1.mov the best way to do this ?
Or can I use the copy funktion for the video as I do for the audio?

/tnx in adv

Comment: Your command is fine. A new file has to be written and video can't be copied.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet if you want to de-interlace and convert to prores without extra loss in quality is to do both actions at once.  Any re-encode, particularly if the encoding you are working from has had consumer level codecs and/or bitrates applied in the past, will cause (potentially significant) additional degradation.  Your best bet is to minimize the number of re-encodes needed by doing as much processing at the same time as you can and maintaining the highest possible image quality as long as possible in your tool chain.

It is unfortunately not possible to make many alterations to video without a re-encode.  There's a limited number of actions that can sometimes be taken, but something like de-interlacing is not included in that list.

Comment: Hello. I have testet now. And Mr. @AJ Henderson, its correct what you wrote. I have to re-capture my videos. ;=( Now I need a filter, I have some white lines on an floor that need to be aligned / corrected. Any suggestion to which ffmpeg filter can handle it. /tnx in Adv.

Comment: @EDBSMED - I am, unfortunately, no expert in FFMPEG.  I normally use other encoders or if I have to use ffMPEG, I use GUI tools.

Comment: Thank you for take time helping me. 
Just pure curiosity, what other encoder do you use?

Comment: A mix of Adobe Media Encoder and the one that Resolve works from.  If I use ffmpeg, I normally do it through Handbrake.